# Embedding Measure into Power Set

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose there is a measure $(\Omega, F, \mu)$, is it always possible to find a measure $(\Omega', P(\Omega'), \mu')$ and function $\psi: F \rightarrow P(\Omega')$ such that $|P(\Omega')|=|F|$ and $\forall E \in F, \mu(E)=\mu'(\psi(E))$? Or in English, is a measure always embeddable into a measure on a power set without excessive cardinality?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function $\psi$? If $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, by definition it is a subset of $P(\Omega)$, so why don't you ask for $\mu(E) = \mu'(E)$ for all $E \in F$?

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend I have updated the question, my intention was to map every limit element of $F$ to a singleton set in the $\mu'$ measure.